# Compartilhamento de Variáveis entre Componentes Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Como faço para utilizar variáveis de um componente Angular no seguinte contexto?
Em um componente eu tenho uma variável que é um array de uma classe criada nesse mesmo componente, essa variável controla os itens selecionados numa lista, segue o código do componente:

```
test: ClasseCriada[]
```

No HTML desse mesmo componente eu falo um NgIf para pegar os itens selecionados e mudar a exibição, dessa forma test.length >= 1

Ocorre que tenho que usar esse mesmo NgIf em outro componente, mas o HTML acusa erro que a propriedade length não pode ser acessada, pois não é uma propriedade.

Tentando solucionar eu usei os decorators @Output e @Input mas não funcionou, pois são componentes que estão na mesma hierarquia e não pai e filho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neste caso você pode utilizar o componente pai para compartilhar os dados entre os irmãos.

No componente onde manipula a lista ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
@Output() testChanged = new EventEmitter<ClasseCriada[]>();
test: ClasseCriada[];

addToTest() {
  //insere no array
  this.testChanged.emit(this.test);
}
```

No componente onde deve receber esta lista ficaria assim:

```
@Input() test: ClasseCriada[];
```

No componente pai ficaria assim:

HTML

```
<a-component (testChanged)="onTestChanged($event)"></a-component>
<b-component [test]="test"></b-component>
```

TS

```
test: ClasseCriada[];

onTestChanged(data:ClasseCriada[]) {
  this.test = data;
}
```

Você pode dar uma olhada nesse link [5 ways to share data between Angular components](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/5-ways-to-share-data-between-angular-components-d656a7eb7f96)